# How to find compiler implementation details?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

It is well known that switch-case constructs can provide better code performance than if-else constructs due to implementation in the form of jump-tables,etc. You can know this only when you know how the compiler implements switch-case. So my question is that how do you get to know how a compiler, for example, Microsoft C++ Compiler or g++, implements a feature? Is there some standard literature available on these topics with respect to common compilers?

Comment: You simply ask for the assembly output of the compiler. A quick google will tell you the option you need to specify for any given compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very useful to get information on `how will a compiler implement a feature` because the compiler runs multiple steps, each will modify the compiled result.

As an example:
A first step build up a meta language, a second step do a first optimization,  next step maybe inline some code, next step...

So you can't get any idea of the code which will be created. So only chance you have: Try it out!

For your example of a switch/case it is important if

1. the case patterns are linear
2. the code inside the pattern is used once or multiple
3. the code return or modify variables or only call other functions
   4 ... tons of other dependencies!

Forget about prediction of optimizer results.

For gcc you have the source, look inside :-)